# How to have constant streamspeed of a GZIP compression?

Tags: java, gzip, chunks

I try to compress-stream a long running process's output. The process is streaming by a constant speed. The compressed output is at a inconstant speed but I do not know why.

Example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ByteArrayOutputStream verboseBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
                long milestone = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                System.out.println("   Wrote (" + len + " bytes) at ms: " + milestone);
                super.write(b, off, len);
            }
        };
        GZIPOutputStream bigChunkOs = new GZIPOutputStream(verboseBAOS, 2048);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20480; i++) {
                    bigChunkOs.write(new Random().nextInt('A', 'z'));
                    if (i % 100 == 0) {
                        System.out.print(".");
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                }
                bigChunkOs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
       Wrote (10 bytes) at ms: 1
..............................................................................................................................................................................   Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 207
      Wrote (367 bytes) at ms: 207
   ...............................   Wrote (2048 bytes) at ms: 243
      Wrote (483 bytes) at ms: 243
```

As you can see, we have 3 steps.

1. Header (~10ms)
2. First block (~207ms)
3. Second block (~243ms)

But I expect more balanced blocks without that ~203ms gap.

What to do?

Comment: Change your expectations?

Comment: After `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()` you are loading two inner classes (and their dependencies), initializing the backend for lambda expressions, starting a new thread, etc., all adding to the time. Further, you are using the single-byte write method no serious application should ever use. Btw, `FlushableGZIPOutputStream` is obsolete since Java 7 and when you use `GZIPOutputStream` directly [you can specify the buffer size](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,int,boolean)) without subclassing

Comment: @Holger Not jdk7 but coyote. Starting the new thread, initializing lambda, load inner clases and their dependencies, all of this took 0ms as you can see in the first line of output. The buffer-size can be ignored but helps in visiualizing as I wrote.

Comment: Have you an absolute need for constant speed for your compression stream? If so what is it? It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, synchronizing things is an extremely hard problem, even if the data is uniform, that's why many systems use buffers. Can a buffer solve your primary need?

Comment: @Kaddath AFAIK a buffer is alreay used. It might matter for energy-efficiency because if I calculate correctly a 1.2kb file (throu a 64kb/s bandwidth) is transported 200ms without compression but 400ms with compression. So you loose speed and electricity if you use compression.

Comment: You are assuming that `System.currentTimeMillis()` was a reliable way to measure elapsed time which it is not. But even if we assume that the time is spent after the first milestone, the first time you’re doing a string concatenation and a `System.out.println` is between the first and second milestone. I don’t know what you want to tell me with “Not jdk7 but coyote”. I know that the class `FlushableGZIPOutputStream` is from a 3rd party library. Still, it’s only purpose is to work-around a limitation that doesn’t exist anymore in Java 7, which makes this class obsolete.

Comment: Yes there is a threshold under which compression adds time, when I had to implement a compression tool we realized that it was better to disable it under a certain length, which you probably have to test yourself (and it won't be universally consistent, in our case it was not vital so an average threshold was fine). I fear constant timing will not be your solution, as you can only slow things down to enforce a certain rate

Comment: @Holger Ah, now I got your point. As the FlushableGZIPOutputStream documentation points out the reason are unsolved bugs, since all the bugs that justify the existence of the FlushableGZIPOutputStream-class are solved, I should not use FlushableGZIPOutputStream anymore. That is a perfect answer from my point of view. could you write this as an answer? Ill mark that as the solution. Oh, let me check if the problem is solved then first.

Comment: That doesn’t mean that it solves your timing problem. It just means you can simplify your code and eliminate one potential problem source. The actual issue seems to be that GZIP buffers far more than you think, so your loop is far ahead of what the `ByteArrayOutputStream` received, then, a large number of small write requests are issued. Add a `System.out.print(".");` at the `sleep` call (which is by the way a `static` method, so you can [and should] write `Thread.sleep(1)`) and you’ll see where the time is spent.

Comment: @Holger I changed the code according to your suggestions. It looks cleaner now, the problem might remain. I mean at some point, the deflator decide to extract a chunk from a couple of 2048-buffers and write multiple 2048-buffers in a bulk update.

Comment: That’s close to what I said; the GZIP compression operates on a much larger buffer. If you specify a buffer size of, e.g. 13000 to `GZIPOutputStream`, you get a steady sequence of write requests at almost fixed rate. Well, if the data is large enough…

Comment: @Holger Ok, and can we reduce that 13000?

Comment: I think, you are simply using the wrong tool for your job. The delays are caused by the `sleep` calls. If you want to reduce the bandwidth and can’t configure the socket to have a reduced bandwidth in the first place, implement a kind of `ThrottlingOutputStream` to operate between the `GZIPOutputStream` and the target `OutputStream` rather than trying to control the timing before passing data to the `GZIPOutputStream`.

Comment: @Holger If I remove the sleep I got: 1ms for the header, **8**ms for the first line of the first chunk and **9**ms for the first line of the second chunk. That might be constant for the chunks but is not constant for the first lines of every chunk. I introduced the sleep to have others - who may have a faster pc than me - be able to reproduce the problem. Others, having a faster pc than me, might have all-0-timings and downvote and close the question for not-reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

The jitter in the output timing is due to the fact that to compress the data the `GZIPOutputStream` (actually, the deflater code in [deflate.c](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libzip/zlib/deflate.c)) needs to buffer the data written into it and only emits a block of compressed data when a certain amount of input data has been added to it.

I've modified your code to get a better understanding of this behaviour:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class Snippet {

    private static long bytesUncompressed = 0;
    private static long prevMilestone = 0;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Random r = new Random();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ByteArrayOutputStream verboseBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
                long milestone = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                System.out.printf("%n   Wrote (%d bytes, uncompressed: %d, timediff=%d) at ms: %d%n", len, bytesUncompressed, milestone- prevMilestone, milestone);
                prevMilestone = milestone;
                bytesUncompressed = 0;
            }
        };
        GZIPOutputStream bigChunkOs = new GZIPOutputStream(verboseBAOS, 16384);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2048000; i++) {
                    bytesUncompressed++;
                    bigChunkOs.write(r.nextInt('A', 'z'));
                    if (i % 100 == 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                }
                bigChunkOs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

This code produces on my machine the following output (only the first few lines):

```
Wrote (10 bytes, uncompressed: 0, timediff=1) at ms: 1
Wrote (12599 bytes, uncompressed: 17287, timediff=461) at ms: 462
Wrote (12776 bytes, uncompressed: 17251, timediff=475) at ms: 937
Wrote (12737 bytes, uncompressed: 17191, timediff=434) at ms: 1371
Wrote (12805 bytes, uncompressed: 17292, timediff=439) at ms: 1810
Wrote (12768 bytes, uncompressed: 17240, timediff=450) at ms: 2260
Wrote (12740 bytes, uncompressed: 17201, timediff=442) at ms: 2702
Wrote (12755 bytes, uncompressed: 17217, timediff=439) at ms: 3141
Wrote (12742 bytes, uncompressed: 17203, timediff=429) at ms: 3570
Wrote (12754 bytes, uncompressed: 17216, timediff=431) at ms: 4001
```

From this it seems that you need to add about 17000 bytes until the deflater writes the first block of compressed data into the underlying OutputStream (the very first block of 10 bytes is the GZIP header) and continues to do so every time you add about 17000 more bytes.

The timing for each block is about 430ms - 460ms (this may be due to load on my machine and other factors).

When I compare these numbers with your sample code then the timing your observe actually makes sense:

- a first block is written into the OutputStream after 207ms, after you've added about 17000 bytes of input data and this first block is about 12000 bytes (actually 6*2048 + 367 bytes of output data)
- the second block is written into the OutputStream after 243ms when you close the GZIPOutputStream. This block is from about 3000 bytes of input data and is 2048+483 bytes of output data.

Comment: Mind that the timing mostly originates from the 172 `Thread.sleep(1)` calls performed by the writing thread when writing 17200 bytes. By all what we know about the precision of a `sleep(1)` call, getting ~400 ms total for a block is very realistic. For the OP’s concern about write speed, only the ratio between the number of source `write` calls and backend `write` calls matters.